# SSM client failing to get Parameters from Lambda in startup

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Running a Lambda on NodeJS 14, using SSM to store my secrets, I regularly (but not all the time) get the following error when requesting parameters using `GetParametersByPathCommand`.

```
{
  "errno":-71,
  "code":"EPROTO",
  "syscall":
  "write",
  "$metadata":{"attempts":1,"totalRetryDelay":0}
}
```

I'm not doing anything super weird. I initialize the SSM client in global scope like this:

```
export const ssmClient = new SSMClient({})
```

And where I use it, is also inside a Promise in global scope:

```
const configPromise = new Promise(async resolve => {
    const configParameters = await ssmClient.send(
        new GetParametersByPathCommand({
          Path: `/PATH_TO_VARS`,
          WithDecryption: true,
        })
      )
    resolve(configParameters.Parameters);
}
```

And then when I need it, inside my controllers, I simply

```
const config = await configPromise;
```

I've seen this pattern used several times, and for me it works a good 90% of the time, but occasionally fails.

Using package `@aws-sdk/client-ssm` version `3.229.0`

Comment: is there a possibility that you hit a throttle? The error you shared isn't really meaningful. What if you have a retry mechanism?

Comment: no, it's not a throttle. Some more searching shows that there are several people facing this issue across AWS services with the NodeJS sdk:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/issues/3513#issuecomment-1234581982